# ResearchKit: Is it possible to get choices variable from ORKConsentReviewStep

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

As my question say, I am creating a **ORKConsentReviewStep** without the signature. But I would like to know if the user tap 'agree' or 'disagree'.

I tried:

```
let reviewResult = result.stepResultForStepIdentifier("kReview")
let r = reviewResult?.resultForIdentifier("kReview") as! ORKChoiceQuestionResult
let choice = r.choiceAnswers?.first as! Double
```

But it will crash.

**Edit:**

I am using this to get the choice from the SharingStep and was hoping the ReviewStep had the same:

```
let sharing = result.stepResultForStepIdentifier("kSharingStep") 
let s = sharing?.resultForIdentifier("kSharingStep") as! ORKChoiceQuestionResult 
let theChoice = s.choiceAnswers!.first as! Double
```

Comment: I think you need to determine why it's crashing. Does `reviewResult` have a value? Is the `resultForIdentifier("kReview")` the type you're *forcing* it to be?

Comment: Yea well, I was hoping it would have a value like that ;) 

I mean because the SharingStep does. It is the same thing but give me a value of 0 or 1 depending if the user want to share or not.

let sharing = result.stepResultForStepIdentifier("kSharingStep")
                    let s = sharing?.resultForIdentifier("kSharingStep") as! ORKChoiceQuestionResult
                    let theChoice = s.choiceAnswers!.first as! Double

Comment: Yeah, sharing step is just a question step, so it behaves the same. The review step is not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this looks like an oversight. Since all our users have used at least `requiresName`, and usually also `requiresSignatureImage`, they have been able to determine whether the user agreed implicitly by whether a name or signature are present.

Note that ORKConsentReviewStep is *not* a question step, so it does not contain a question result. Its result's child is an `ORKConsentSignatureResult` which documents the name and/or signature obtained.

What *should* happen is that if the user does not agree, the review result should have a flag to indicate this explicitly.

I've filed [#244](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/244)

Answer (score 0):

While looking through the files and trying to create an own delegate I found

```
@protocol ORKConsentReviewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)consentReviewControllerDidAcknowledge:(ORKConsentReviewController *)consentReviewController;
- (void)consentReviewControllerDidCancel:(ORKConsentReviewController *)consentReviewController;
@end
```

So here is the answer to my own question :)

Comment: That's internal to the framework and shouldn't be used at the app level. The _documentReviewed flag it sets needs to get propagated up to the result.

Comment: @jwe : yes I noticed that. But the app I am creating doesn't need a signature. I just want to see whether they agree or disagree with the terms of the app. And then continue with the app if the user agrees.

Comment: This change is now in master.